# Calculate closures in functional analysis

Tags: functional-analysis

I have a solved the following exercise  :

> Let $A=\{p(x)=(x^4-1)q(x) \mid q \text{ even polynomial} \}$.
> Calculate the closure of $A$ in 1) $C([-2,2])$, 2) $C([-1/2,1/2])$ and 3) $C([0,1/2])$

Solution:

1. $\{f\in C([-2,2]) \mid f(x)=f(-x) \text{ for all } x\in[-2,2], f(1),f(-1) \neq 0  \}$
2. $\{f\in C([-1/2,1/2]) \mid f(x)=f(-x) \text{ for all } x\in[-1/2,1/2]  \}$
3. $\{f\in C([0,1/2])\}$

using the following Theorem:

> Let $A\subset C(k,\mathbb R)$ subalgebra and $f\in C(k,\mathbb R)$. Then $f\in \overline A$ if and only if:
>
> i) $\forall x\ne y \in K$ such that $f(x) \ne f(y)\Rightarrow \exists g\in A$ such that $g(x)\ne g(y)$
>
> ii) $\forall x \in K$ such that $f(x) \ne 0\Rightarrow \exists g\in A$ such that $g(x)\ne 0$

My question is, what would be the difference between case $3)$ and if we are asked to calculate the closure of $A$ in $L^p([0,1/2])$?
I think the closure is the same but I am not sure.

Thank you